# Convolution of two rectangular pulses

Tags: graphing-functions, convolution

> Determine the shape of the following function$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \Pi(4\tau) \Pi(t-\tau) d\tau$$

**Attempt:**

This function is a convolution of two rectangular functions. I know that the result has to be a triangular pulse, but how do we determine the width and the height of this triangle?

I know that the first term is just a rectangular pulse compressed by a factor of 4. Here's a picture showing $\Pi(4\tau)$ (magenta) compared to $\Pi(\tau)$ (blue):

[image]

But what about $\Pi(t-\tau)$? And how do I work out the width of the convolution of the two?

Comment: Whenever a convolution problem shows up, it's always a sensible idea to consider the Fourier transform e.g. $\mathcal{F}[h]=\mathcal{F}[f]\mathcal{g}$ where $h(t)=(f\star g)(t)$. This is enough, for example, to deduce the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t)\,dt$ since this should be $\mathcal{F}[h]$ evaluated at zero frequency (up to an overall constant, I suppose).

Comment: So the convolution is the individual Fourier transforms multiplied. The first term becomes $\Pi(4\tau) \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} sinc \left( \frac{\nu}{4} \right).$ Now, for the second term, $\Pi(t-\tau),$ do I need to take the Fourier transform of $\Pi(\tau)$? And what would be the overall result? A sinc function overlapped on a smaller sinc function?

Comment: I had a typo above: Should've been $h(t)=(f\star g)(t)\implies \mathcal{F}[h](\nu)=\mathcal{F}[f](\nu)\cdot \mathcal{F}[g](\nu)$. In this case you'd just end up with $\frac{1}{4} \text{sinc}\left( \frac{\nu}{4} \right)\cdot \text{sinc }\nu$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define the rectangular pulses as follows

$$p_1 (t) := u \left(t + \frac{T}{2}\right) - u \left(t - \frac{T}{2}\right)$$

$$p_2 (t) := u \left(t + \frac{T}{8}\right) - u \left(t - \frac{T}{8}\right)$$

where $u$ is the **Heaviside step**. Let $x = p_1 * p_2$. When convolving piecewise constant functions, a useful "trick" is to differentiate

$$\dot x (t) = (\dot p_1 * p_2) (t) = p_2 \left(t + \frac{T}{2}\right) - p_2 \left(t - \frac{T}{2}\right)$$

and then integrate

$$x (t) = r \left(t + \frac{5T}{8}\right) - r \left(t + \frac{3T}{8}\right) - r \left(t - \frac{3T}{8}\right) + r \left(t - \frac{5T}{8}\right)$$

where

$$r (t) := \begin{cases} t & \text{if } t \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

is the **ramp** function.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

1. Since the pulses have different widths you don't get a triangle but a trapezoid
2. Take for example $t = 100$, then $\Pi(4\tau) \Pi(t-\tau)$ is zero for all $\tau$. What's the smallest and the largest $t$ such that the integral is non-zero? This gives you the width of the resulting pulse.
3. For what range of $t$ do the two pulses overlap completely (like in your plot)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You mean in the sense that a triangle is a special form of a trapezoid?